# json parsing using dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a json file that look like this:
I will have to extract the events eg. 'APP_STARTED' 'ORIENTATION' etc

```
{u'ParamElement_ReceivedTime': u'2012-11-02-00-05-31-748', 
 u'ParamElement_Name': u'LOG_CONTENT', 
 u'ParamElement_Info_0': 
                 {u'dict': 
                      {u'Events_list': [
                          {
                           u'Event': u'APP_STARTED', 
                           u'time': u'2012-11-01 20:00:59.565 -0400'}, 
                          {
                            u'time': u'2012-11-01 20:01:01.168 -0400', 
                            u'Event': u'ORIENTATION', 
                            u'Orientation': u'Portrait'}, 

                          {u'Event': u'CLIENT_RESULT_RECEIVED', 
                           u'time': u'2012-11-01 20:01:15.927 -0400'}, 

                          {u'Prev_SessionID': u'802911CC329E47139B61B58E21BF2FFF', 
                           u'Prev_TransactionID': u'2', 
                           u'Tab_Index': u'5', 
                           u'time': u'2012-11-01 20:01:15.941 -0400', 
                           u'Event': u'RESOLVED_TAB', 
                           u'Accuracy': u'5.000000'}, 

                          {u'Prev_TransactionID': u'2', 
                           u'Prev_SessionID': u'802911CC329E47139B61B58E21BF2FFF', 
                           u'Event': u'CLIENT_RESULT_RECEIVED', 
                           u'time': u'2012-11-01 20:01:16.568 -0400'}
                    }
```

The whole thing is stored in a variable called event_dict.
I have a code that looks like:

```
if event_dict:
      if 'dict' in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']:
          if 'el' in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']['dict']:
           if 'e' in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']['dict']['el']:
             print e['Event']
```

What could be the mistake?

Comment: *What* mistake? What error or incorrect behavior are you getting?

Comment: no error.  I tried to print dict and it is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python approach is ***Ask forgiveness, not permission***, and it is easier and better to use `try-catch` blocks instead of `condition checks` unless `condition fail` must be handled separately.

```
try:
    event = event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']['dict']['Events_list']
except Exception, e:
    log('Opsss, incorrect data format: %s' % e.message)
```

In that way, you can see your errors easily.

Answer (score 2):

You never define the variable `e`: your last line should be a loop, *not* a conditional like the earlier lines:

```
for e in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']['dict']['el']:
    print e
```

Also, I think you say `"el"` when you would need to say `"Events_list"`, making your corrected code:

```
if event_dict:
      if 'dict' in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']:
          if 'Events_list' in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']['dict']:
              for e in event_dict['ParamElement_Info_0']['dict']['Events_list']:
                  print e
```

Comment: Yes i use el for Events_list

Comment: What do you mean you "use el"? The name of the string in your dictionary is `Events_list`. You are checking whether that string is in your dictionary. You can't check for an entirely different string. Did you mean for it to be a for loop, like `for el in event_dict...`?

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning for el in event_dict...  I did not change it back to event_list.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: This prints 'Event' and its value.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'el' element in your dictionary.  When you write a `for A in B` you are creating a variable A to hold the contents of the iterable B.  What you are doing is saying, if the key 'el' is in my dictionary... which it isn't.  But Events_list is as @David points out.

Here is what may be an easier approach.

```
def item_getter(struct, key):
    parts = key.split('.', 1)
    if len(parts) > 1:
        key_part, rest_part = parts
        return item_getter(struct.get(key_part, {}), rest_part)
    return struct.get(key, None)

items = item_getter(event_dict, "ParamElement_Info_0.dict.Events_list")
events = [item.get('Event', 'No Event') for item in items]
print events
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[u'APP_STARTED', u'ORIENTATION', u'CLIENT_RESULT_RECEIVED', u'RESOLVED_TAB', u'CLIENT_RESULT_RECEIVED']
```